What gets rid of lack-of-citation notices?
What gets rid of these notices?:

Want to improve this answer? Add details and include citations to explain why this answer is correct. Answers without enough detail may be edited or deleted.

For example, it is still on one of my answers, even though citations were added over a year ago.

Added one final note to my answer - if you spot a citation notice anywhere that it no longer belongs, or think there is further action that should be taken, please raise a Flag and we'll get it looked at!

Ah, so these notices are all manually added and removed by Moderators. Usually when we've added a note like this we also have an active flag open against the post - we leave it a few days, check in again and then either remove the notice or delete the post if it hasn't improved.
In this case the only flag the post had open against it was "too many comments", and that was cleared after the comments were cleaned up and sent to chat. So it looks like it just got forgotten about.
Occasionally you will see posts out there with open notices without flags, usually these are high enough quality that we wouldn't delete them unilaterally, but still lack references.
Finally, if you spot any post notices out there that you think need to be removed or actioned (content deletion), please raise a Flag and we'll get it sorted.
